# What normal forms are these two relations in?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I have a set of relations {A, X, Y, Z}:

Given that the functional dependencies:  AX→Y, AX→Z, Y→A, Z→X, I would think that this relation would be in the normal form 1NF, because there is a partial dependency for the composite key, YZ; Y determines A and Z determines X. However, I ran across this example on a university website claiming the relationship was in 3NF. Am I wrong about this relation being in 1NF?

On a similar note, given the same relation but with functional dependencies:  A→XY, Y→AZ, would this be in 3NF or BCNF, I do not see any reason why this would not be in BCNF, but I have seen a similar example where there was a further decomposition, that was also BCNF. So is the decomposition wasteful because the original relation with given dependencies was already in BCNF?

Answer (score 4):

The relation is actually in 3NF (so that it is also in 1NF and 2NF). The reason is that each attribute of the relation is *prime*, that is, it belongs to a (candidate) key (the are four keys in this relation: `(A X), (A Z), (X Y), (Y Z)`).

The definition of the 2NF (which has only an historical interest), is the following (Database System Concepts, 6th edition, Korth, Silberschatz, Sudharshan):

> A functional dependency X → Y is called a *partial dependency* if there is a proper subset Z  of  X such that Z  → Y . We say that Y  is partially dependent on X. A relation schema R is in *second normal form* (2NF) if each attribute A in R meets one of the following criteria:
>
> • It appears in a candidate key.
>
> • It is not partially dependent on a candidate key.

so the relation respects this definition, since each attribute appear in a key.

While the definition of Third Normal Form is (same source as above):

> A relation schema R is in *third normal form* with respect to a set F of functional dependencies if, for all functional dependencies in F<sup>+</sup> of the form  X → Y, where  X ⊆ R and Y  ⊆ R, at least one of the following holds:
>
> • X  →  Y is a trivial functional dependency.
>
> • X is a superkey for R.
>
> • Each attribute A in Y − X is contained in a candidate key for R.

so the relations respects this definition too.

For your second question, the relation has two keys, `A` and `Y`, and it is already in BCNF as well as in 3NF.

Note that the analysis algorithm to decompose a relation in BCNF should return the original relation, since no dependency violates its definition (each determinant is a superkey).